# JavaScript remove object from array if value exists in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I am using Firebase, so if there is a more efficient way to structure this data in order to be able to query only the cards that have not already been viewed by the logged in user, I am open to going that route as well. Right now I am trying to do the filtering after the fact.

I have an array of all cards included in my application that looks like this:

[image]

I have a second array that holds information on all the cards the user has already seen. I want to be able to look through both arrays, and if the cid in Array two matches the $id in Array 1, then remove that object entirely from Array 1.

[image]

Comment: you can follow my answer.  and it was same as the one you have accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the arrays and use splice to remove the element

```
for(var i =0; i< array2.length; i++ ) {
   for(var j= 0; j< array1.length;j++) {
     if (array2[i].$id === array1[j].$id) {
      array1.splice(j,1);
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

This is actually very easy to do in a functional way:

`array1 = array1.filter(item => array2.every(item2 => item2.cid != item.$id));`

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns, as an array, the elements of an array that cause the supplied function to return `true`. And our filter-evaluator says 'return true if there is no item in array2 whose CID matches this item's ID'.

Because `filter()` is returning a new array, there's no need to use `splice()`; we can just reassign array1 to the newly filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use one array of objects for that. keep a object key for that

> seen

by default keep **seen** false. and use [firebase-query](http://[1]https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html) where the column seen is false.

or you can do something like that after fetching the data in your code.

```
var resultarray = [];

for(var i =0; i< array1.length; i++ ) {
   var flag = true;
   for(var j= 0; j< array2.length;j++) {
     if (array1[1].$id === array2[2].$id) {
       flag = false;
       break;
    }
  }
  if(flag === true) {
    resultarray.push(array1[i]);
  }
}
```