# How to remove objects from root of array if a duplicated is found in a Children object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The current code works with no problem. I like to know if there is a cleaner or better way to remove objects from the root of my array if a value is found somewhere in a nested object. I want to remove the object

```
const baseArray = [
    {
        title: 'Test folder',
        UUID: '54F5E250-1C5F-49CC-A963-5B7FD8884E48',
        Children: [
          {
            title: 'nothing',
            UUID: 123,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'nothing',
        UUID: 123,
      },
    ]

  const currArray = baseArray

  const removeRootUUID = (baseArray, currArray) => {
    const delInRoot = uuidRef => {
      baseArray.forEach((obj, i) => {
        if (obj.UUID === uuidRef) {
          baseArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
      });
    };
    for (const obj of currArray) {
      if (obj.Children) {
        obj.Children.forEach(node => {
          delInRoot(node.UUID);
        });
        removeRootUUID(baseArray, obj.Children);
      }
    }
  };
```

output I am looking for is below. (because UUID is founded in root and in another nested object)

```
{
        title: 'Test folder',
        UUID: '54F5E250-1C5F-49CC-A963-5B7FD8884E48',
        Children: [
          {
            title: 'nothing',
            UUID: 123,
          },
        ],
      }
```

Comment: What will `currArray` be on the first call of `removeRootUUID`?

Comment: Just updated code. currArray is the same as baseArray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript remove object from array if value exists in other array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177097/javascript-remove-object-from-array-if-value-exists-in-other-array)

Comment: Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nsqzw034/), I started coding until I realized I wasn't quite sure what the intended output should be. Because you said that the current code works, I copied it into the fiddle as I want to know if the results there are consistent with what you require.

Comment: Sorry I updated the code. Please try to run it on fiddle again @Vektor